# How may I bind a Toast progress bar with my C++ Win32 application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, toast

I'm creating a c++ Win32 application which should show some Toast notifications. One of them contains a progress bar. I need to bind its value with my application in order to update it while the status changes in the currently running operation.

The Toast interface containing the progress bar is defined as follow:

```xml
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>Backup in progress</text>
            <progress title='Working folder' value='0' status='Starting backup...' valueStringOverride='0/1 files' />
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

To show the Toast notification I call the following function, by passing the above interface in the `toastContent` string:

```cpp
bool ShowToastNotification(const std::wstring toastContent)
{
    if (!toastContent.length())
        return false;

    // build XML
    ::CComPtr<ABI::Windows::Data::Xml::Dom::IXmlDocument> pDoc;
    HRESULT hr = DesktopNotificationManagerCompat::CreateXmlDocumentFromString(toastContent.c_str(), &pDoc);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    // create the notifier. Classic Win32 apps MUST use the Compat method to create the notifier
    ::CComPtr<ABI::Windows::UI::Notifications::IToastNotifier> pNotifier;
    hr = DesktopNotificationManagerCompat::CreateToastNotifier(&pNotifier);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    // create the Toast notification (using helper method from Compat library)
    ::CComPtr<ABI::Windows::UI::Notifications::IToastNotification> pToast;
    hr = DesktopNotificationManagerCompat::CreateToastNotification(pDoc, &pToast);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    // get access to IToastNotification4, which should contain the binding methods
    ::CComPtr<ABI::Windows::UI::Notifications::IToastNotification4> pToastData;
    pToast->QueryInterface(ABI::Windows::UI::Notifications::IID_IToastNotification4, (void**)&pToastData);

    ABI::Windows::UI::Notifications::INotificationData* pData = nullptr;

    // FIXME how may I create a valid INotificationData here?

    // bind the data with the interface
    hr = pToastData->put_Data(pData);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    // show it
    hr = pNotifier->Show(pToast);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

As you can see in the FIXME part above, there is a missing part to achieve the binding before showing the Toast notification, and unfortunately there is absolutely **NO** documentation from Microsoft which explain how to perform that in a simple C++ Win32 application. The below one explain clearly how to perform a such binding, but only in C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-progress-bar?tabs=builder-syntax

Even without documentation I could find that the `IToastNotification4` seems to be a valid interface to attach a `INotificationData` container to my Toast, similar to what is done in the above mentioned documentation. However I don't know how to create a valid `INotificationData` instance. I saw that a `CreateNotificationDataWithValuesAndSequenceNumber()` function exists in the `INotificationDataFactory` interface, but same thing, I face a cruel miss of documentation about how to obtain a such interface.

Can someone explain me how I may bind my C++ Win32 application with my progress bar on my Toast notification, in order to send it messages to update its interface? Or can someone explain me how to get the above mentioned interfaces, in order to perform something similar to the above mentioned C# documentation? Or at least can someone point me a documentation which may give information about the `INotificationData` and `INotificationDataFactory` interfaces, and how to use them to perform the binding with my Toast progress bar?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/app-notifications/app-notifications-quickstart?tabs=cpp

Comment: Isn't this? [Send and update a progress bar notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/app-notifications/app-notifications-quickstart?tabs=cs#send-and-update-a-progress-bar-notification).

Comment: Thank for the above mentioned document, unfortunately it not serves for me, because I haven't the required WinRT includes available. It's probably because I'm writing a Win32 Desktop app, whereas this documents seems to target an UWP one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a WinRT class can be created from C#, it means it's activatable (or it's associated with another "statics" class which is), which you can check if you go to [NotificationData documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.notificationdata):

```
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Activatable(262144, "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract")]
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Activatable(typeof(Windows.UI.Notifications.INotificationDataFactory), 262144, "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract")]
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ContractVersion(typeof(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract), 262144)]
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.MarshalingBehavior(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.MarshalingType.Agile)]
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Threading(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ThreadingModel.Both)]
public sealed class NotificationData
{...}
```

If it's activatable, then you just have to find it's activation class id, and call [RoActivateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roapi/nf-roapi-roactivateinstance) . The class id is visible in the corresponding .h file (here `windows.ui.notifications.h`) and it's usually very straightforward: `<namespace> + '.' + <class name>`:

```
...
extern const __declspec(selectany) _Null_terminated_ WCHAR RuntimeClass_Windows_UI_Notifications_NotificationData[] = L"Windows.UI.Notifications.NotificationData";
...
```

So here is how you can create it:

```
HRESULT CreateNotificationData(INotificationData** data)
{
    if (!data)
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    *data = nullptr;
    IInspectable* instance;
    auto hr = RoActivateInstance(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_UI_Notifications_NotificationData).Get(), &instance);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = instance->QueryInterface(data);
    instance->Release();
    return hr;
}
```

PS: using [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt) is usually easier to use than ATL, WRL or WIL for WinRT types.